# How safe is current_user_can()?

Tags: security

I'm saving sensitive data via JSON ajax request, it is not sanitized,  literally anything can be passed.

I need to make sure that only admins with `edit_options` permission can save it.

So I do:

```
function received_ajax_request() {
  if ( !current_user_can('edit_options') ) {
    return;
  }

  save_to_database( $_POST['something']) );
}
```

My question is how safe it is? Do I need to check for anything else besides `current_user_can`?

For example, I saw some other plugins check also for nonce, but when rest API is used - nonces are generally not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`current_user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) checks whether current user has a specific capability. And only that...

**It won’t protect you from XSS attacks** - so it would be a good idea to check some *nonces* too - this way you can be certain that user wants to perform given action.

*Let’s say there’s a link to delete a post. Of course you will check if user can delete posts. But what if a user is logged in and I make him click the link? He doesn’t have to know - it can be a shortened link or an image.*

**It also won’t check if the current user is owner of given object.**

*Let’s day I’m a customer in shop. Of course I can add comments to orders. But only for my orders.*

So you should always check full access rights and not only roles and capabilities.

**And of course it won’t make the action safe.** So you still have to sanitize, and escape, and so on...